# How do I convert a CString to a double in C++?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, double, type-conversion

How do I convert a `CString` to a `double` in C++?

Unicode support would be nice also.

Thanks!

Comment: I really cant believe this hasn't been asked yet...but search revealed nothing.   If it's a duplicate, please be gentle :)

Comment: Couldn't find the answer here either, but googling "cstring to double" gets you the correct answer on the first hit.

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge indeed it does, if by "the correct answer" you mean this page right here :)

Comment: @aquirdturtle I deserved that. I've learned not to write such comments in the last 7 years :-)

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge heads up: a bit more than 3 years later, this page is still the top result.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A `CString` can convert to an `LPCTSTR`, which is basically a `const char*` (`const wchar_t*` in Unicode builds).

Knowing this, you can use [`atof()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012.aspx):

```
CString thestring("13.37");
double d = atof(thestring).
```

...or for Unicode builds, [`_wtof()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012.aspx):

```
CString thestring(L"13.37");
double d = _wtof(thestring).
```

...or to support both Unicode and non-Unicode builds...

```
CString thestring(_T("13.37"));
double d = _tstof(thestring).
```

(`_tstof()` is a macro that expands to either `atof()` or `_wtof()` based on whether or not `_UNICODE` is defined)

Comment: This link shows you "wcstod" which is what I used to support unicode.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab(VS.80).aspx

Comment: This works, but IMO MighMoS's suggestion of std::stringstream is a bit cleaner.

Comment: _wcstod_l / _tcstod_l allows one to specify locale, so one can handle localized format (decimal delimiter as comma or dot etc.)

Answer (score 5):

You can convert *anything to anything* using a `std::stringstream`. The only requirement is that the operators `>>` and `<<` be implemented. Stringstreams can be found in the `<sstream>` header file.

```
std::stringstream converter;
converter << myString;
converter >> myDouble;
```

Comment: This sounded good to me. Unfortunately it didn't work for the questioned scenario here with the Microsoft (MFC) CString type. I got this compiled, but the converted double number seemed to be random, at least it had no relation to the string. I hope, it works good for other types which implement the << and >> Operators better. I am no expert yet in using the std strings in C++, but to me a converter which results in wrong numbers without throwing an error or exception is very dangerous.

Comment: Remark: The other Suggestion here, _tstof() worked fine for converting a CString to a double for me.

Comment: @Philm: This answer **can** be used with MFC's `CString` objects just fine. You don't need an `operator<<()` either. That's what the constructor is for: `std::wstringstream converter(myString);`. Note that this requires a `CStringW` (which, in the majority of cases, is the correct type anyway). However, there's still a silent killer in there. It seems to be clear, elegant. And wrong. It uses the current thread locale for the conversion. This may or may not be what you want. Better to use a solution that allows you to explicitly specify the locale to use for the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

with the boost lexical_cast library, you do

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
using namespace boost;

...

double d = lexical_cast<double>(thestring);
```

Answer (score 1):

[strtod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab(VS.80).aspx) (or [wcstod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab(VS.80).aspx)) will convert strings to a double-precision value.

(Requires `<stdlib.h>` or `<wchar.h>`)

Comment: Consider some more context to the page you're adding

Comment: Usage examples wouldn't go amiss either... See the accepted answer.